# 500 Error after uploading Bitnami / XAMPP Wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I have been working offline and have uploaded my work to my domain. Everything works fine, however when trying to load other pages I get a 500 error

In the error it mentions localhost. I have uploaded from localhost, but I updated the appropriate values in wp_options to my domain. So I can't figure out why its still referring to localhost

Clearly localhost is persisting somewhere, but where?

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: It might be worth posting the contents of your server error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resetting your permalinks?

I get 500s and 404s a lot when removing plugins that rely on permalink references.

Try going to the Settings>Permalinks and clicking on another option than the one currently saved. Save it. Wait for the page to reload. Then go back to the permalinks option you want and resave.

The 500 just might repair itself this way.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem! I would never have suspected it though, as when mousing over or loading links it displayed my domain rather than localhost.

Comment: Cool. Please vote up the answer as this will help me in return.

Comment: This answer helped me greatly in my Bitnami LAMP server. Thank you for posting.